# SQL error in a MySQL query with alias (AS)

Tags: mysql, sql

I had problem while executing this SQL statement in MySQL workbench. Can anyone point out the problem for me?

```
SELECT concat(LocationName,' - ', StationName) AS LocationStation, EmpName AS '0000-0100', EmpName AS '0100-0200', EmpName AS '0200-0300', EmpName AS '0300-0400', EmpName AS '0400-0500', EmpName AS '0500-0600', EmpName AS '0600-0700', EmpName AS '0700-0800', EmpName AS '0800-0900', EmpName AS '0900-1000', EmpName AS '1000-1100', EmpName AS '1100-1200', FROM satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE LocationName = 'T2 PML'
and AllocationDate = '10-Aug' 
and (EmpTime >= '00:00:00' and EmpTime <= '12:00:00')
```

The above statemnt prompted me this error, "You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use neat 'FROM satsschema.employeeslot WHERE LocationName = 'T2 PML' and AllocationDate = ' at line 1."

Secondly, Is there any other ways that could make this line shorter besides typing everything out?

```
EmpName AS '0000-0100', EmpName AS '0100-0200', EmpName AS '0200-0300', EmpName AS '0300-0400', EmpName AS '0400-0500', EmpName AS '0500-0600', EmpName AS '0600-0700', EmpName AS '0700-0800', EmpName AS '0800-0900', EmpName AS '0900-1000', EmpName AS '1000-1100', EmpName AS '1100-1200', FROM satsschema.employeeslot
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try removing the ','  before the `FROM`

Comment: What's the point in giving more than one alias to one column ?

Comment: The 1hour break time indicates the header and the values inside will be the employees that were working in the time slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma before `FROM`. It causes the error.

```
SELECT concat(LocationName,' - ', StationName) AS LocationStation, EmpName AS '0000-0100', EmpName AS '0100-0200', EmpName AS '0200-0300', EmpName AS '0300-0400', EmpName AS '0400-0500', EmpName AS '0500-0600', EmpName AS '0600-0700', EmpName AS '0700-0800', EmpName AS '0800-0900', EmpName AS '0900-1000', EmpName AS '1000-1100', EmpName AS '1100-1200' FROM satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE LocationName = 'T2 PML'
and AllocationDate = '10-Aug' 
and (EmpTime >= '00:00:00' and EmpTime <= '12:00:00')
```

Note that the error message said exactly where was the error.

In MySQL, the `AS` keyword is optional for column aliasing, so you may write `EmpName '0000-0100'` in place of `EmpName AS '0000-0100'`. I don't think there is a short solution to give more than one alias to one column as it's really not something that is often necessary.

Comment: Yep I understand but giving more then 1 alias in this case for me is to let the user know which employees falls inside the time slot. It's like a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `comma` before `from` clause.

```
SELECT  concat(LocationName,' - ', StationName) AS LocationStation, 
        EmpName AS '0000-0100', 
        EmpName AS '0100-0200', 
        EmpName AS '0200-0300', 
        EmpName AS '0300-0400', 
        EmpName AS '0400-0500', 
        EmpName AS '0500-0600',
        EmpName AS '0600-0700', 
        EmpName AS '0700-0800', 
        EmpName AS '0800-0900', 
        EmpName AS '0900-1000', 
        EmpName AS '1000-1100',
        EmpName AS '1100-1200'   -- remove comma here
FROM satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE LocationName = 'T2 PML'
and AllocationDate = '10-Aug' 
and (EmpTime >= '00:00:00' and EmpTime <= '12:00:00')
```